# Convert SQL Server datetime to Int

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime, datatable

I have a SQL Server database with a column that stores datetime, I want to convert all of those column values to an integer for example:

[This is my database it has some null values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhGxW.png)

and what I want is that it displays in a datagridiew, this type of value:

Output: "17:30"

and after that, separate those two values in:

Output: 17, 30

So that I can do operations with it, here is my code so far:

```
public DataTable SQLToInt() 
{
    comando.Connection = Conexiion.AbrirConexion();
    comando.CommandText = "SELECT HLunesE FROM Grupos$";

    leer = comando.ExecuteReader();

    while (leer.Read())
    {  
    }

    tabla.Load(leer);        
    Conexiion.CerrarConexion();

    return tabla; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command instead:

```
comando.CommandText = "SELECT concat(DatePart (Hour,HLunesE),',',DatePart (Minute,HLunesE)) as Result
                       FROM Grupos$ WHERE HLunesE IS NOT NULL";
```